# Not able to run the recorded autoI script

Tags: autoit

> "C:\Program Files\AutoIt3\SciTE\AutoIt3Wrapper\AutoIt3Wrapper.exe" /ShowGui /in "C:\Program Files\AutoIt3\SciTE\hellsoft.au3"
>   +>10:18:52 Starting AutoIt3Wrapper v.2.0.1.24    Environment(Language:0409  Keyboard:00000409  OS:WIN_XP/Service Pack 2  CPU:X64 OS:X86)
>   -> 2 Change(s) made.
>   Running AU3Check (1.54.19.0)  from:C:\Program Files\AutoIt3
>   C:\Program Files\AutoIt3\SciTE\hellsoft.au3(4,1) : WARNING: #comments-start has no explicit closing #comments-end (1 level).
>   C:\Program Files\AutoIt3\SciTE\hellsoft.au3 - 0 error(s), 1 warning(s)
>   ->10:19:00 AU3Check ended.rc:1
>   Running:(3.3.6.1):C:\Program Files\AutoIt3\aut2exe\aut2exe.exe  /in "C:\Program Files\AutoIt3\SciTE\hellsoft.au3" /out "C:\Program Files\AutoIt3\SciTE\hellsoft.a3x" /nopack /comp 2
>   !>10:19:09 Aut2exe.exe ended errors because the target exe wasn't created, abandon build.rc:9999
>   Exit code: 0    Time: 17.672

Comment: Well, it says "the target exe wasn't created" -- have you checked for permissions issues? What credentials is the shell running under?

Answer (score 2):

You have an error message telling you that you have a `#comments-start` without a corresponding `#comments-end`.

Open up your au3 in SciTE and do a Ctrl-F5. You can double click the warning message and it will take you right to the `#comments-start` that needs to be removed or ended (with a `#comments-end`.